# Example of a compact set on $\mathbb{R}$ that is not rectifiable

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying the book Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres and there is this question that I cannot solve. I imagine that it is a quite stranger set... I appreciate any hints, comments, suggestions.

Comment: A Cantor set of positive measure?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, it works! I was wondering about it. Do you know any construction?

Comment: Try [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) or just google ["Cantor" "set" "positive measure"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cantor+set+%22positive+measure%22). Once you have an example in ${\mathbb R},$ call it $C,$ you can get an example in ${\mathbb R}^n$ (for $n \geq 2)$ by taking the Cartesian product of $C$ with $n-1$ many sets, each of which is either $C$ or a compact interval.

Comment: By the way, *WHY* such a set works depends on what you know (at this point in the book) about compact rectifiable sets (other authors call them compact Jordan measurable sets).

Comment: What is a rectifiable set? Does it just mean its boundary has measure 0?

Comment: @zhw: I had to look it up at an amazon.com preview (or maybe it was a google-books preview) before my first comment, since I don't have a copy of this book nor knew what the term meant. It's a set such that the Riemann integral over that set of the constant function $1$ exists. So it's just a Jordan measurable set from what I gather. (Unless "bounded" is not part of what a Jordan measurable set is. I suspect definitions vary slightly on this issue.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks. Yes, I'm gathering that a rectifiable set is a bounded subset with boundary of measure 0.

Comment: @zhw: By the way, for some reason I didn't notice that you followed-up with "Does it just mean its boundary has measure 0?" Maybe this was added while I was writing my comment, or maybe I just overlooked it, but I would have said YES to that aspect if I had noticed it (in case you're wondering why I didn't address the "measure 0 of the boundary" aspect in my comment).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Actually it was probably added during that time frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Painless Cantor type set: The rationals $\mathbb Q$ have measure $0,$ so there is an open set $U$ containing $\mathbb Q$ such that $m(U)<1/2.$ The set $\mathbb R \setminus U$ is then a closed set with empty interior (because it contains no rational). The set $E =(\mathbb R \setminus U)\cap [0,1]$ is then a compact set with empty interior. Furthermore $[0,1]$ is the disjoint union of $E$ and $U\cap [0,1].$ The latter set has measure less than $1/2,$ so $m(E) > 1/2.$ Because $E$ has empty interior, $\partial E = E.$ Therefore $E$ is a compact nonrectifable subset of $\mathbb R.$

Comment: nice answer, I really enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is Exercise 5 on p.120 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

> Example 1 on p.113:
> We construct a bounded open set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\operatorname{Bd}A$ does not have measure zero.
>
> The rational numbers in the open interval $(0,1)$ are countable; let us arrange them in a sequence $q_1,q_2,\dots$. Let $0<a<1$ be fixed. For each $i$, choose an open interval $(a_i,b_i)$ of length less than $\frac{a}{2^i}$ that contains $q_i$ and is contained in $(0,1)$. These intervals will overlap, of course, but that doesn't matter. Let $A$ be the following open set of $\mathbb{R}$: $$A=(a_1,b_1)\cup (a_2,b_2)\cup\dots.$$

The author proved that $\operatorname{Bd}A$ doesn't have measure zero.

So, $A$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ that is not rectifiable.
Since $A$ is open, $\mathbb{R}-A$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.
$[0,1]$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.
So, $[0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A)$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.
$[0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A)$ is obviously bounded.
So, $[0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A)$ is a bounded closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.
We prove that $[0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A)$ is not rectifiable.
Assume that $[0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A)$ is rectifiable.
Note that $[0,1]=([0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A))\cup ([0,1]\cap A)=([0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A))\cup A$ and $([0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A))\cap A=\emptyset$.
Obviously, $[0,1]$ is rectifiable.
By Exercise 2 on p.120, $[0,1]-([0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A))$ is rectifiable.
Since $[0,1]-([0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A))=A$, $A$ is rectifiable.
This is a contradiction.
So, $[0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A)$ is not rectifiable.
$[0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A)$ was a bounded closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.
So, $[0,1]\cap(\mathbb{R}-A)$ is a bounded closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ that is not rectifiable.